# IIS doesn't serve .webp images even it's configured to

Tags: iis

When I run project locally, I use:

```
<staticContent>
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".webp" mimeType="image/webp" />
</staticContent>
```

in `Web.config` file to see `.webp` images in browser and everything works fine. There's a dedicated server where IIS is running, I configured MIME types to serve `.webp` images:
[image]

I also restarted IIS to apply this change.

But `Content-Type` of `.webp` images is always `text/html`. I also tried the approach which I used locally - error still persists.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The was not in IIS (as usual).

My images were not included in `.csproj` file so they weren't pulled by CI/CD to working directory. I just don't understand how it haven't respond with `404` but loaded "images" from jenkins directory somehow